# replace element of string 3 - 10 positions after a pattern

Tags: r, string

Ideally, in base R I need some kind of string manipulation that will let me detect a pattern and change the string 3 positions after the pattern.

```
    example <- "when string says SOMETHING = #c792ea"
```

desired output:

> when string says SOMETHING = #001628

I have tried gsub but I am not sure how I can get it to replace the characters after a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it based on the position of character, then we can use `substring` assignment

```
substring(example, 30) <- "#001628"
example
#[1] "when string says SOMETHING = #001628"
```

---

Or if we need to find the position of the word that starts with `#`

```
library(stringr)
posvec <- c(str_locate(example, "#\\w+"))
substring(example, posvec[1], posvec[2]) <- "#001628"
# // or with 
# str_sub(example, posvec[1], posvec[2]) <- "#001628"
```

Another option is `sub` to change the substring after the `=` and one or more space (`\\s*`)

```
sub("=\\s*.*", "= #001628", example)
#[1] "when string says SOMETHING = #001628"
```